# Error: ENOENT using __dirname

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I use express to write my website. This is my code in server.js

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/add', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "add.htm");})
```

My project structure:

```
core
    server.js
public
    add.html
```

But when I am trying to go to the http://localhost:9000/add I get this error:

Error: ENOENT, stat '...\Project\REST\core\add.html'
   at Error (native)

Why does it looking for add.html in core folder?

Comment: Path is relative so you don't have to mention `res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "add.htm")` everytime just put your files under public dir and acces like
`res.sendFile("add.htm")`

Comment: Now I have "TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile"

Comment: You should look into this http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I use the same code in my project but still have this error in my program.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it looking for add.html in core folder?

Because `__dirname` reflects the directory of the JS file that uses it (it does *not* reflect the current working directory).

In your case that file is `core/server.js`, so `__dirname` is `FULL-PATH-TO/core/`.

The path to `add.html`, relative to `server.js`, is this:

```
__dirname + "/../public/add.html"
```

Comment: I have tried to change my path but now I have this error: "ForbiddenError: Forbidden"

Comment: If you're using Windows you may have to reverse those forward slashes: `__dirname + "\\..\\public\\add.html"`.

Comment: I want to add that when I use `app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "index.html");
})` it works like it should. But for /add it doesn't work at all.